# Warnings When Objects are not Being Lazy Loaded in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I was wondering if there was a way to tell Hibernate to generate some kind of console warning when it has too many objects of a certain type in the session cache. I would like to do this for load testing as we have `OutOfMemoryException` problems on occasion with BLOB loading from Oracle.

We are still using `Hibernate 3.6.10` for now. Our best approach for this testing at the moment is to just generate more data than the system would be able to handle in a normal use case and try to load the parent object and see if it crashes. Doing it this way just feels kind of bad.

Any suggestions are welcome.

One note that I forgot to mention is that this "logging" idea is something I would like to be able to leave in production code to pinpoint specific problems.

**- EDIT -**

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

Say I have an `@Entity ClassX` that has a lazy loaded list of `@Entity ClassY` objects. Some how, I would like to have a log message spit out when 100 or more instances of `ClassY` are loaded into the session cache. This way, during development I can load a `ClassX` object and notice if I (or another developer on the team) happen to be accessing that list when I shouldn't be.

Comment: Are those objects entities or components? (Is this about entries in the session cache, or particular fields of those entries?)

Comment: I'm talking mostly about the entities themselves, but the ability to track the components might be nice as well. I'll try and update my question with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could attach an `Interceptor` to listen to object load events, maintaining a count for each unique entity type and logging a warning whenever it goes past a certain threshold. [The documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/events.html) shows you how to define a session-scoped interceptor, by passing it in at creation time:

```
Session session = sf.openSession( new AuditInterceptor() );
```

Most likely you're not creating your Session manually so this may not be helpful, but possibly the way that you are declaring your session has some way of passing an `Interceptor` through.

It's easier to declare a SessionFactory-scoped Interceptor but it doesn't seem to give you any reference back to the Session that the object is being created within, otherwise you'd be able to knock up some sort of counter in a `WeakHashMap` (with Session as the key so that you don't leak memory). If you're using the default Thread-local session strategy then you could always ask `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`.

Comment: This is excellent -- in fact, probably exactly what I wanted. We will give this a shot when we have some more time. Just for reference, we are using Spring to establish sessions, and will likely just inject the interceptor.